# Extract value from a JSON array with no name

Tags: json, sql-server, extract, json-value

I have a table with a record that has JSON content and it is an array with no name. Sample data looks like this:

| carId | carType | parts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z003 | Company | `[{"Value":"New","Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":"Upgraded","Type":"Doors","Code":"E1"}]` |
| Z003 | Company | `[{"Value":null,"Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":null,"Type":"Doors","Code":"E1"}]` |
| Z003 | Company | `[{"Value":"USed","Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":"New","Type":"Tires","Code":"G7"}]` |

There are actually about 20 to 30 classes within the array but i have shown only 2 for simplicity. So for each record I am trying to extract certain classes with certain attributes into their own field. Like so:

| carId | carType | BrakesCode | DoorsValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z003 | Company | D | Upgraded |
| Z003 | Company | D | null |
| Z003 | Company | D | null |

I have tried numerous queries and have not succeeded. Here is my latest:

```
SELECT carId, carType, JSON_VALUE( JSON_QUERY(parts,'$[0]'),'$[0].Code')
FROM [Assets].[dbo].[Cars]
```

Which results in:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 4.

I know I have to insert a WHERE somewhere so I can match the Type=Brakes but am unsure where that goes. Any help appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to parses our JSON text and returns objects and properties from the JSON input as rows and columns, then we use `MAX()` With `CASE` to get the expected data,

```
with cte as (
  SELECT carId, carType, Code, Type, value
  FROM Cars
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([parts], '$')
  WITH (
    Code NVARCHAR(50) '$.Code',
    Type NVARCHAR(50) '$.Type',
    value NVARCHAR(50) '$.Value'
  )
)
select carId, carType,
  MAX(case when Type = 'Brakes' then Code end) as BrakesCode,
  MAX(case when Type = 'Doors' then [Value] end) as DoorsValue
from cte
where Type in ('Brakes', 'Doors')
group by carId, carType
```

Result :

```
carId   carType BrakesCode  DoorsValue
Z001    Company D           Upgraded
Z002    Company D           null
Z003    Company D           null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/93zYc3mO)

Comment: True but the data is not guaranteed to be in any order, Thus why I think I have to add a WHERE Type="Brakes" somewhere but not sure where.

Comment: Can you check my update

Comment: Yes! that has put me on the right path. I think i can tweak it a little and get what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One more method.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, carId CHAR(4), carType VARCHAR(20), parts NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (carId, carType, parts) VALUES
('Z003', 'Company', '[{"Value":"New","Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":"Upgraded","Type":"Doors","Code":"E1"}]'),
('Z003', 'Company', '[{"Value":null,"Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":null,"Type":"Doors","Code":"E1"}]'),
('Z003', 'Company', '[{"Value":"USed","Type":"Brakes","Code":"D"},{"Value":"New","Type":"Tires","Code":"G7"}]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH brakes AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
        , BrakesCode = JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.Code')
    FROM @tbl AS t
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(parts) AS j
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.value) AS j2
    WHERE j2.[key] = 'Type'
        AND j2.value = 'Brakes'
)
, doors AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
        , DoorsValue = JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.Value')
    FROM @tbl AS t
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(parts) AS j
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.value) AS j2
    WHERE j2.[key] = 'Type'
        AND j2.value = 'Doors'
)
SELECT t.ID, t.carId, t.carType, BrakesCode, DoorsValue
FROM @tbl AS t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN brakes ON t.ID = brakes.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN doors ON t.ID = doors.ID;
```

**Output**

| ID | carId | carType | BrakesCode | DoorsValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Z003 | Company | D | Upgraded |
| 2 | Z003 | Company | D | NULL |
| 3 | Z003 | Company | D | NULL |